# Can I somehow tag data in Redis?

Tags: caching, redis

I have an object `Company` and multiple methods that can be used to get this object. Ex. `GetById`, `GetByEmail`, `GetByName`.
What I'd like is to cache those method calls with a possibility to invalidate all cache entries related to one object at once.

For example, a company is cached. There are 3 entries in cache with following keys:

1. `Company:GetById:123`
2. `Company:GetByEmail:foo@bar.com`
3. `Company:GetByName:Acme`

All three keys are related to one company.

Now let's assume that company has changed. Then I would like to invalidate all keys related to this company. I didn't find any built-in solution for that purpose.
Tagging cache entries with some common id (companyId for example) and then removing all entries by it would be great, but this feature doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question directly, You'd probably want to maintain all the keys related to your company in a list, scan through that list, and delete all the associated keys with a DEL command.

So something like:

```sh
LPUSH companies-keys:Acme Company:GetById:123 Company:GetByEmail:foo@bar.com Company:GetByName:Acme
```

Then

```sh
RPOP companies-keys:Acme
```

and for each entry you get out of the list:

```sh
UNLINK keyname
```

To answer it not so directly, you may want to consider using a [Hash](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-1-getting-started/chapter-1-getting-to-know-redis/1-2-what-redis-data-structures-look-like/1-2-4-hashes-in-redis/) rather than just keys, that way you can just modify one of the fields in the hash rather than having to invalidate all the keys associated with it.

So you could create it with:

```sh
HSET companies:123 id 123 email foo@bar.com name acme
```

Then you could update a particular entry in the company record with HMSET:

```sh
HMSET companies:123 email bar@foo.com
```

Since it sounds like being able to look up a given record by different fields is really important to your use case - you may also want to consider adding [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) and indexing the fields you want to be able to search on different fields for the set of fields listed above, and index of:

```sh
FT.CREATE companies-idx ON HASH PREFIX 1 companies: SCHEMA id TAG email TEXT name TEXT
```

Might be appropriate - then you could look up a company with a given email like:

```sh
FT.SEARCH companies-idx "@email: foo"
```

Comment: The problem with solution with ```list``` is that in this case I'll need one list key to access that list-with-keys. So In order to access company by email I must know company name (according to provided example). Hash accompanied with RediSearch seems to cover all my needs, but I'd rather keep it simple and not modify existing Redis setup. Will investigate further, but thanks anyway.